# Illegal inheritance compilation error using Scala 2.7.7 and LIFT 1.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: lift, scala-2.7

I am using JDK 1.6.0_16, and Scala 2.7.7, compiling with maven.

I do `mvn clean compile` and I get four errors, but they are identical, in different models:

> [ERROR]
>   C:\Users\owner\workspace\ResumeApp\src\main\scala\jblack\resumeapp\lift\
>   model\ContactInfoModel.scala:13:
>   error: illegal inheritance;
>
> [INFO]  self-type
>   jblack.resumeapp.lift.model.ContactInfoModel
>   does not conform to
>   net.liftweb.mapper.CRUDify[Long,jblack.resumeapp.lift.model.ContactInfoModel]
>   's selftype
>   net.liftweb.mapper.CRUDify[Long,jblack.resumeapp.lift.model.ContactI
>   nfoModel] with
>   jblack.resumeapp.lift.model.ContactInfoModel
>   with net.liftweb.map
>   per.KeyedMetaMapper[Long,jblack.resumeapp.lift.model.ContactInfoModel]
>
> [INFO]          with CRUDify[Long,
>   ContactInfoModel] {

And this is my code:

```
package jblack.resumeapp.lift.model

import net.liftweb.mapper._

object ContactInfoMetaData 
    extends ContactInfoModel 
        with KeyedMetaMapper[Long, ContactInfoModel] {
    override def dbTableName = "contactinfo"
    override def fieldOrder = List(key, data, display) 
}
class ContactInfoModel 
    extends KeyedMapper[Long, ContactInfoModel] 
        with CRUDify[Long, ContactInfoModel] {
    def getSingleton = ContactInfoMetaData
    def primaryKeyField = id

    object id extends MappedLongIndex(this)
    object key extends MappedString(this, 100)
    object data extends MappedString(this, 100)
    object display extends MappedBoolean(this)
}
```

I am not certain what I am doing wrong.

Unfortunately, because I installed the nightly plugin, into Eclipse, I can't install IDE 2.7.7, so I can only compile this with maven.

Is there a problem with how I am using `CRUDify`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRUDify in lift-1.1 needs to be mixed into the MetaMapper object instead of the Mapper class.  So it should work with this code instead:

```
package jblack.resumeapp.lift.model

import net.liftweb.mapper._

object ContactInfoMetaData 
    extends ContactInfoModel 
        with KeyedMetaMapper[Long, ContactInfoModel]
        with CRUDify[Long, ContactInfoModel] {
    override def dbTableName = "contactinfo"
    override def fieldOrder = List(key, data, display) 
}
class ContactInfoModel 
    extends KeyedMapper[Long, ContactInfoModel] {
    def getSingleton = ContactInfoMetaData
    def primaryKeyField = id

    object id extends MappedLongIndex(this)
    object key extends MappedString(this, 100)
    object data extends MappedString(this, 100)
    object display extends MappedBoolean(this)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have since started to move to using JPA so I will see what problems I have. :) And using LIFT 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working properly when I went back to using LIFT 1.0 instead of 1.1. It appears that there is some change that I need to eventually look into for 1.1, but at least I can continue with my development.